# Changing Foreign key

Tags: mysql

So I have created a table with two columns containing foreign keys using MySQL. The problem is that these two columns contain numbers instead of names and details. Is there any way to change the appearance of the foreign key?

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you mean?

Comment: Are you talking about the foreign key? which is a number? what is the foreign key linked to?

Comment: Your Foreign Key has to match perfectly the Primary Key in datatypes and columns! If the datatype of the stored values are different you cannot create the constrain.

Comment: show both table structure parent/child.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys need to match the Primary key of the related table.

For an user interface, you normally use a query to
get details from the related table. To avoid data duplication you do not
want to have details of the foreign data set in the original table.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization and related articles
for suggestions how to organize your data best.

Comment: I want to then create a list for the information and if they are all numbers it will not make sense, i want to be able to change it to make it more of a user interface

Comment: You need to distinguish between data representation / database layout and user interface. A good database layout is usually not directly user-friendly (but allows easy extension, takes less disk space, is flexbile, does avoid data duplication etc.).  An user-interface shows normally no ids/numbers but replace it by the detail information. You usually do not want to have user direct access to the database and therefore do not need to be user-friendly there.

Comment: How do you replace or link the ids from the child table with detailed information from the parent table?